# How can we adjust the hAxis ticks location with Google Bar Chart?

Tags: javascript, charts

I'm encountering an issue when using Google Charts. The hAxis tick locations appear differently when using a bar chart. When using a line chart, the hAxis position is correct. However, when using a bar and line combo chart, the hAxis position is incorrect.

```js
function drawChart() {
  var dataArray21 = [
    ['Date', 'Hs (m)', 'Ts (s)'],
    [new Date(2023, 3, 17, 0, 0, 0), 0.566, 6.636],
    [new Date(2023, 3, 17, 1, 0, 0), 0.368, 5.033]
  ];
  var tickMarks = [];
  var today = new Date()
  var tmp1 = today - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
  var yesterday = new Date(tmp1)
  yesterday.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
  for (var j = 0; j < 24; j++) {
    hour = new Date(yesterday.getTime() + (j * 60 * 60 * 1000))
    tickMarks.push(hour);

  }

  var data21 = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataArray21);
  var chart21 = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.querySelector('#chart_div_21'));
  var options21 = {
    series: {
      0: {
        'color': '#76A7FA',
        targetAxisIndex: 0,
        lineWidth: 1,
        pointSize: 3,
        'type': 'bars'
      },
      1: {
        'color': '#191970',
        targetAxisIndex: 1,
        lineWidth: 0,
        pointSize: 3
      },
    },
    vAxes: {
      0: {
        format: "#0.0",
        ticks: [0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0],
        textStyle: {
          color: '#76A7FA',
          fontSize: 14,
          bold: true
        }
      },
      1: {
        textPosition: 'out',
        format: "0.0",
        ticks: [0, 1.5, 3.0, 4.5, 6.0, 7.5, 9.0],
        textStyle: {
          color: '#191970',
          fontSize: 14,
          bold: true
        }
      },
    },
    hAxis: {
      format: "HH",
      textPosition: 'out',
      gridlines: {
        color: "#000000"
      },
      baselineColor: '#000000',
      ticks: tickMarks,
      textStyle: {
        bold: true,
        color: '#000000'
      },
    },
    explorer: {
      focusTarget: 'category',
      actions: ['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset'],
      axis: 'horizontal',
      keepInBounds: true,
      maxZoomIn: 6.0
    },
    chartArea: {
      width: '90%',
      height: '80%'
    },
    colors: ['#D44E41']
  };

  chart21.draw(data21, options21);

  var chart22 = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.querySelector('#chart_div_22'));
  var options22 = {
    series: {
      0: {
        'color': '#76A7FA',
        targetAxisIndex: 0,
        lineWidth: 1,
        pointSize: 3,
        'type': 'line'
      },
      1: {
        'color': '#191970',
        targetAxisIndex: 1,
        lineWidth: 0,
        pointSize: 3
      },

    },
    vAxes: {
      0: {
        format: "#0.0",
        ticks: [0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0],
        textStyle: {
          color: '#76A7FA',
          fontSize: 14,
          bold: true
        }
      },
      1: {
        textPosition: 'out',
        format: "0.0",
        ticks: [0, 1.5, 3.0, 4.5, 6.0, 7.5, 9.0],
        textStyle: {
          color: '#191970',
          fontSize: 14,
          bold: true
        }
      },
    },
    hAxis: {
      format: "HH",
      textPosition: 'out',
      gridlines: {
        color: "#000000"
      },
      baselineColor: '#000000',
      ticks: tickMarks,
      textStyle: {
        bold: true,
        color: '#000000'
      },
    },

    explorer: {
      focusTarget: 'category',
      actions: ['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset'],
      axis: 'horizontal',
      keepInBounds: true,
      maxZoomIn: 6.0
    },
    chartArea: {
      width: '90%',
      height: '80%'
    },
    colors: ['#D44E41']
  };
  chart22.draw(data21, options22);
};
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {
  'packages': ['corechart'],
  'callback': drawChart
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="chart_div_21"> </div>
  <div id="chart_div_22"> </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm encountering an issue when using Google Charts,
the hAxis ticks location appears differently when using a bar chart, if we use line chart, the hAxis position is different with use bar chart.
as shown in the link."
 [hAxis ticks location is not sync](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FTgz.png)

the options hAxis is  as below:

```
hAxis:  {
        format:"HH", textPosition: 'out',gridlines: {color: "#000000"}, baselineColor: '#000000',
    ticks: tickMarks,textStyle:{bold:true,color:'#000000'},
                        },
```